# Get Binary Attribute from a MongoDB document in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

Well, I am creating dumped objects using a ByteArrayOutputStream. And then will write them to MongoDB as an attribute in my documents. When I read it back how can I convert it to a byte array or a Binary without using a toString in the middle?

This is the way I do it now, and I dont think it is safe:

```
BasicBSONObject temp = (BasicBSONObject) models.get("0");
model = null;
    if (temp != null) {
        // TODO fix this serialization!
        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(temp.toString().getBytes()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            L.error("unable to read model from string!");
            L.error(e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try the temp.get("<key>") and casting to your target object?  If that doesn't work, I guess, you might not have the option other than toString

Comment: I suggest you convert the byte array to a base64 string before save it in mongodb. In read operation, first decode the base64 to a byte array.

Comment: @MiguelCartagena Thank you but I guess that will be too much overhead....

Comment: @HRahimi I store some small files in MongoDB in that way ... without overheads.